# How can I parallelize multiple instances of the same Selenium suite using Junit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests

I have a Junit test suite that I am using to run a series of selenium tests.  I need to run these tests on several platforms (browser/OS combos, mobile devices).  Is there a way for me to run the suite in parallel with 4 other instances of the same suite (5 total), each with different config settings (settings for the RemoteWebDriver).

Should I us a parallelized runner (I've seen a few options) on each test within the suite or parallelize the suite itself?

Also, is there a way to run a sequence of these parallel runs? (i.e. 5 parallel runs followed by another 5 parallel runs, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) for this.

To run tests in parallel with JUnit4, you will also need [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Running_tests_in_parallel).

Comment: I am using browserstack as a multi-browser testing service, which seems to fill the same role as Selenium Grid.  I'm looking for a way to run multiple tests at the same time.

Comment: @prototypetolyfe You will need Maven; see link in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Selenium grid does not provide the parallel distribution of your tests, it is simply a way to allow multiple threads hit the same endpoint to support parallel testing.

You still need a mechanism to support the parallel distribution of your tests.

I know this can be achieved with JUnit, but in my experience it is easier with TestNG